# Updating Accounts shows: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>

Tags: api, integration, duplicate-management

I am Trying to update one Field in Account using postman but it's not letting me update it. I also Turned off history tracking for an Account. I have given full access to my app in Salesforce. 
eg

```
https://test.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Account/2236I111ULVqnRLE
data = {
    "Name": "Test Company"
}
```

I also tried with the query but still, the same issue occurs. how can I figure out what's the problem is? 
one more thing it is allowing me to update values for some of the accounts. what more I can check. Please help me with this
​​​​​​​
[image: Postman Request]

Comment: The error seems to be coming from a standard duplication rule which is turned on at your org?

Comment: What does this post have to do with the `Salesforce Communities` feature? Please try to only apply tags which are relevant to your question.

Answer (score -2):

this error is probably throwing due to duplicate rules(standard/custom) that has already been there in your org.

To tune this issue, you can  try it same thing for contact object.

https://test.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Contact/2236I111ULVqnRLE
data = {
    "LastName": "Test Company"
}

if it's updated successfully without any error then there is no issue with how you calling the REST API

Comment: I tried updating one contact and it's been updated. I don't understand whats the problem in updating Accounts